# What is the ruby regex to get a specific part of this URL?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, url

I'm trying to get the ASIN of some Amazon items. I found a pattern: the ASIN is always after "/dp/". How can I extract the ASIN (B003CP0V6S) from that string?
I'm using ruby

```
url = "http://www.amazon.it/Calvin-Klein-Deluxe-K0S21120--Orologio/dp/B003CP0V6S/ref=lp_1597641031_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1349983393&sr=1-8"
```

Comment: When I have a question like this, I always go to http://www.rubular.com - a fantastic little utility that lets you tweak regex's and learn how the different options work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
str = "http://www.amazon.it/Calvin-Klein-Deluxe-K0S21120--Orologio/dp/B003CP0V6S/ref=lp_1597641031_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1349983393&sr=1-8"
(match = str.match(/\/dp\/([^\/]*)/)) && match[1]
# => "B003CP0V6S"
```

Comment: I got an error:  str.match(/\/dp\/([^\/]*)/)) && match[1]
SyntaxError: (irb):27: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end
str.match(/\/dp\/([^\/]*)/)) && match[1]

Comment: That's because you cut-and-pasted the code without getting the `(match =` from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Some people like to use an alternate syntax when writing Ruby regular expressions for use with URLs, because all the escaping of slash characters hinders readability.  Enclosing the regular expression in `%r{}` lets you leave the forward slashes unescaped.

```
  str = "http://www.amazon.it/Calvin-Klein-Deluxe-K0S21120--Orologio/dp/B003CP0V6S/ref=lp_1597641031_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1349983393&sr=1-8"
  (str =~ %r{/db/(.+?)/} && $1)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't stand well on its own without a definition of `str`: it doesn't match the OP's url.

Comment: @pje, ok, assignment to `str` is added.

Answer (score 0):

```
url.split("/dp/").last.split("/", 2).first
```

should do.